# Socket.io opening a second connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

## Requirements

I have the following user requirements:

1. Document A can be edited in real-time by `n users`
2. User A can edit the `document A` and everyone connected to `document A` should see changes in real time
3. The same goes for `documents B, C, D, ..., n`

I'm currently using socket.io in an express server to handle the real-time communication. The logic (reduced to a minimal reproducible example) is as follow:

1. As soon as user opens `document A`, he joins a room by emitting an event `join:room` to the websocket server
2. websocket server attaches the user to room `document A`
3. `user A` writes something on `document A`, `user B` will receive the updates in real-time
4. `user B` leaves `document A`, he emits an event `leave:room` to websocket server

## Minimum reproducible example

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*"
  }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join:room', (data) => {
    console.log(`Joined room: ${data.roomId}`);

    socket.join(data.roomId);
  });

  socket.on('text:insert', (data) => {
    console.log(`Text inserted: ${data.roomId}`);

    socket.to(data.roomId).emit('text:inserted', data);
  });

  socket.on('leave:room' , (data) => {
    console.log('left room: ' + data.roomId);
    socket.leave(data.roomId);
  });
})
```

The code on the client is as follow (reproduced to a minimal reproducible example):

```js
// main.js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

window.io = io;
console.log('opened connection');
window.monacoSocket = io(process.env.MIX_WEBSOCKET_SERVER_URL);

// custom.js
function onTextInserted({ user, event }) {
  console.log('Text have been inserted: ' + event);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.files')
  .forEach((item) => {
    item.dblclick(() => {
      window.monacoSocket.removeAllListeners();

      window.monacoSocket.on('text:inserted', ({ event, user }) => onTextInserted({ user, event }));
    });
  });
```

This codes works great when we are working in the same document

## The problem

The problem starts when I move from `document A` to `document B`. Whenever I open my page and visit **only** `document A`, I can see that only a single websocket connection was opened and everything works as expected (from both `user A` and `user B` perspective):

[image]

Now, if I follow the following steps:

1. as `user A` I open `document A`
2. as `user B` I open `document A`
3. as `user A` I make a change in `document A`
4. as `user A` I switch to `document B`
5. as `user A` I make changes to `document B`
6. as `user B` I see a new connection opening in my `network tab`

As soon as this new connection is opened, `user A` and `user B` will not be receiving changes anymore

[image]

## Questions

I have a couple of questions to help me understand what exactly is going on here.

1. When I add new listeners to a `socket.io-client` instance, should the `socket.io` library open a new connection as it is doing right now?
2. What exactly is causing the new connection to be opened? Is it safe to assume that if no new connection would be open, the code should work as intended - the `console.log` in `onTextInserted` function should print?
3. On my anonymous function on `dbclick`, should I see remove all listeners?

I highly appreciate anyone taking the time to answer these questions.

Comment: Hi! I wasn't able to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-fiddle/tree/issues/so-73802227

Could you please check?

Comment: @darrachequesne indeed I'm unable to reproduce as well. I will investigate further to see what exactly is causing the error on my side. This is definitely an socket.io error but more likely to some logic of my app